# Can you have multiple endpoints/functions from a single .NET Core project in Google Cloud Run?

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a single `.NET Core` .proj file and a single Google Cloud project. The .NET Core project is very simple with a single class implementing `IHttpFunction` and implementing `HandleAsync` which is the entrypoint. I have a Cloud Build trigger connected to this project's Git repository which is set to run whenever a commit is pushed into main.

I would like to have more functions-- and hoping to not duplicate common functionality between them -- add those functions to the same project. But when I have multiple classes implementing `IHttpFunction`, Cloud Build fails.

I think there are at least 2 other ways to do this:

- Deploy manually and select a function - but can I do this with Cloud Build triggers too?
- Have all functions go through a single "dispatcher" endpoint - which seems messy

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't know .NET core framework and I can't help you on that part. However, on Cloud Run, you simply have to webserver. A webserver listen on a port (most of the time 8080), and can serve several path. If you can run that locally, you are able to package that in a container and to deploy it on Cloud Run without issue.

Comment: You will either need to deploy separate Cloud Run services (containers) or use a dispatch (routing). Using a dispatch is the norm.